# Unable to run webpack with socket.io and React

Tags: node.js, sockets, reactjs, express, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to the whole React, webpack and express frameworks, but I was able to get my React and webpack components running fine until I decided to integrate socket.io and express for some real time notifications. Here is my server side code in server.js:

```
// Babel ES6/JSX Compiler
require('babel-register');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var Router = require('react-router');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var routes = require('./routes');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var swig  = require('swig');
var webpack = require("webpack");
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");

var server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: webpackConfig.output.path,
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  filename: path.resolve(webpackConfig.output.path, webpackConfig.output.filename),
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
  stats: { colors: true }
});


var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(PORT);

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("Welcome to the Web Portal");

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Goodbye');
  });

});

app.post("/notify", function(req, res) {
  var title = req.body.title;
  var description = req.body.description;
  io.emit('notification', title + '\n'+ description);
  res.send("Notification received");
});
```

and here is my client side code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="background-grey">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.0.0/codemirror.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.0.0/theme/solarized.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


  </head> 
  <body class="background-grey">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();

      socket.on('notification', function(message) {
        alert(message);
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm basically rendering my React components through webpack-dev-server since when I did it the standard way through the react-middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  Router.match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var html = ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps));
      var page = swig.renderFile('index.html', { html: html});
      res.status(200).send(page);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
    }
  });
});
```

it was giving me this issue `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(DashBoard)"` when I tried to go to the url directly.

Also, when I tried to comment out `var server = require('http').createServer(app);` so that `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` would be calling the server from the WebpackDevServer, but then it throws me this error:

```
  var listeners = server.listeners('request').slice(0);
                         ^
```

I've looked at almost all of the posts and articles online but I was unable to implement them in my code. Can someone please give me instructions on how can I run my server and render all of the React components correctly and also have socket.io integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what I was doing wrong earlier, but I started over and reconstructed my project structure. Then I set up socket.io in server.js and followed the documentation to send/receive data on the client side, and it worked perfectly. My boilerplate project for React, Express and Webpack can be found here: [React Express Webpack Boilerplate Project](https://github.com/rjzheng/REWBoilerplate)